# How to create relationships among similar/parallel paths in neo4j?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm looking for a way to batch create relationships among similar/parallel paths in neo4j.

A sample graph may look like this:

[image]

As you can see, the pink node(the one in the center) `:WRAPS` 3 yellow nodes, and each yellow node `:WRAPS` 2 red nodes. I'm trying to create 3 `:PARALLEL` relationship between each possible pair of 3 nodes. I tried this Cypher statement:

```
MATCH (pink:Slide)-[:WRAPS]->(yellow:GroupBox)-[:WRAPS*]->(red:Content)
WHERE pink.uuid = "ca7e1d47-1fbe-4008-9617-ef41c8a04316"
MATCH path = (yellow)-[rel]->(red)
RETURN path
```

It returns all yellow nodes and the associated red nodes. The graph looks like this:

[image]

However, since path's class is `Path`, not `List`, I can't use unwind/foreach to loop through them. I also tried `relationships(path)` but it's returning a bunch of empty arrays. I intend to compare the length of and labels of nodes in each path, but can't find a way to do so. Could you help with it?

Answer (score 0):

### Creating your graph

For the ease of possible further answers and solutions I note my graph creating statement:

```
CREATE
  // left bunch
  (pink:PinkNode {name: '369'})-[:WRAPS]->(yellow1:YellowNode {name: '190'}),
  (yellow1)-[:WRAPS]->(red1:RedNode {name: '201'}),
  (yellow1)-[:WRAPS]->(red2:RedNode {name: '198'}),
  (pink)-[:WRAPS]->(red1),
  (pink)-[:WRAPS]->(red2),

  // upper bunch
  (pink)-[:WRAPS]->(yellow2:YellowNode {name: '195'}),
  (yellow2)-[:WRAPS]->(red3:RedNode {name: '204'}),
  (yellow2)-[:WRAPS]->(red4:RedNode {name: '208'}),
  (pink)-[:WRAPS]->(red3),
  (pink)-[:WRAPS]->(red4),

  // lower bunch
  (pink)-[:WRAPS]->(yellow3:YellowNode {name: '192'}),
  (yellow3)-[:WRAPS]->(red5:RedNode {name: '208'}),
  (yellow3)-[:WRAPS]->(red6:RedNode {name: '210'}),
  (pink)-[:WRAPS]->(red5),
  (pink)-[:WRAPS]->(red6),

  // "free" red ones
  (pink)-[:WRAPS]->(red7:RedNode {name: '255'}),
  (pink)-[:WRAPS]->(red8:RedNode {name: '166'}),
  (pink)-[:WRAPS]->(red9:RedNode {name: '264'}),
  (pink)-[:WRAPS]->(red10:RedNode {name: '269'});
```

### Solution

All possible relationships between your three nodes pairs you will achieve with the following Cypher statement:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.COMMIT('
MATCH
  (pink:PinkNode)-[:WRAPS]->(yellow:YellowNode)-[:WRAPS]->(red:RedNode)
WITH yellow AS startNode, yellow AS endNode WHERE NOT (startNode)-[:PARALLEL]->(endNode) AND id(startNode) < id(endNode)
CREATE (startNode)-[:PARALLEL]->(endNode)
RETURN count(*)
', {limit: 10000});
```

### Underlying Idea

Based on the identification and selection of your three-nodes-pairs in line 3, I check in line 4 if your desired `:PARALLEL` relationship already exists. If not, I create it (line 5). By means of the [APOC library](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) I rerun this statement until all relationships are created.

> Especially for graph processing it is useful to run a query repeatedly
>   in separate transactions until it doesn’t process and generates any
>   results anymore. So you can iterate in batches over elements that
>   don’t fulfill a condition and update them so that they do afterwards.
>
> The query is executed repatedly in separate transactions until it
>   returns 0.

([taken from Neo4j APOC procedure index at GitHub](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index33.html#_apoc_periodic_commit))

The id comparison in line 4 avoids having two relationships per pair (one in each direction) and prevents creating the relationship from nodes to themselves.